# notepad++ before 3 digits character replace

Tags: notepad++, regex

notepad++ before 3 digits replace
Example:

Replace * to \n before 3 or more digits
This four lines

```
452*52*625
652*5*622
252*265*6262*45222
2525*2565*2552
```

i want this Result only 3 or more digits before * replace

```
452*52
625
652*5
622
252
265
6262
45222
2525
2565
2552
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### I want to replace `*` with `\n` before 3 or more digits

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `\*(\d{3,})`.
- Set "Replace with" to `\n\1`
- Enable "Regular expression" and "matches newline"
- Click "Replace All"

Notes:

- Use `\r\n` for Windows EOLs
- Use `\n` for Unix/OSX EOLs
- Use `\r` for Mac OS (up to version 9) EOLs

  [image]

**Before**:

```
452*52*625
652*5*622
252*265*6262*45222
2525*2565*2552
```

**After**:

```
452*52
625
652*5
622
252
265
6262
45222
2525
2565
2552
```

---

#### Further reading

- [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++ (tutorial)](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)
- [RegExper: Regular Expression Visualiser](https://regexper.com/)

Answer (score -1):

yes i find

Find

```
\*[0-9]{3}
```

Replace

```
\n$&
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It produces https://i.imgur.com/9lOgILH.png, which is not what you asked for :)